# Discord.py code to give message author a role

Tags: python

So I have a variable called `ownerid` where I store a discord account's ID. I want a way so that when I log into that Discord account, and type a command, the bot checks whether my ID and the `ownerid` match. If it does, then to give me the Admin role. I tried this code:
`prefix` is the bot's prefix
`guildid` is my server ID the bot is in.

```py
  if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'give admin'):
    if message.author.id == ownerid:
      member = message.author
      role_name = 'Admin'
      guild = client.get_guild(guildid)
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_name)
      await member.add_role(role)
```

However I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'add_role'
```

And I don't understand how to fix it and get my code working. And yes, the Admin role that the bot is trying to give is under the Bot's role, so there shouldn't be a problem, because the bot has administration permissions as well. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: It is `add_roles`

Comment: Still I am getting an error.
'AttributeError : 'NonType' object has no attribute 'id'`